# Cron doesn't execute

Tags: php, cron, mysql

in crontab e

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/domain.com/backUp.php
```

in backUp.php

```
<?php
$dbFile = '/var/www/domain.com/db-cron-backup/tb_db_backup'.date('H').date('d').date('Y').sql.gz';
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // Database Host
$dbUser = 'username'; // Database Username
$dbPass = 'password'; // Database Password
exec( 'mysqldump --host="'.$dbHost.'" --user="'.$dbUser.'" --password="'.$dbPass.'" --databases "db_name" | gzip > "'.$dbFile.'"' );
?>
```

But nothing happens?

Permisions for db-cron-backup

`drwxrwxrwx  2 root root     4096 Nov 10 15:01 db-cron-backup`

Comment: have you tried with manual execution ?

Comment: check this  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Comment: @JanithChinthana ah why it doesn't come to my mind at first? :O there was a syntax error :) thx

Answer (score -1):

if you want it to run every three hours then set the cron to

```
0 */3 * * *
```

Comment: i think its not in time? because it never execute... what execution time do i have set now? Just to be sure...